# How add a range of data o OLAppointment.Body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, appointment

I have this routine that works perfectly fine. The issue is that under the part of OLAppointment.Body I am referencing many cells but I have rearranged my data so all of the data I want to include in OLAppointment.Body is in range Worksheets("Manager County Info").Range("D7:I17")
but I don't know how to code OLAppointment.Body to accept a range.

Anyone know how I can do this?

```
Sub Appointments()
Const olAppointmentItem As Long = 1
Dim olApp As Object
Dim OLNS As Object
Dim OLAppointment As Object
Call GetData
formattedHTHLL = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("R" & ActiveCell.Row).value, "$#,##0")
formattedBond2LL = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("S" & ActiveCell.Row).value, "$#,##0")
formattedBond3LL = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("T" & ActiveCell.Row).value, "$#,##0")
formattedBondSP = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("U" & ActiveCell.Row).value, "$#,##0")
formattedTaxes = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("E7").value, "$#,##0")
formattedSellerStamps = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("E8").value, "$#,##0")
formattedCredit = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("E4").value, "$#,##0")
formattedDownPayment = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("G6").value, "$#,##0")

Worksheets("Manager County Info").Range("D7").value = Worksheets("Loans").Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).value
On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If olApp Is Nothing Then Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not olApp Is Nothing Then

    Set OLNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    OLNS.Logon

    Set OLAppointment = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    OLAppointment.Subject = Worksheets("Loans").Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).value & " (LGI 
    Builder LO - " & Worksheets("Loans").Range("K" & ActiveCell.Row).value & ")" _
    & " COE " & Worksheets("Loans").Range("W" & ActiveCell.Row).value & " (" & 
    Worksheets("Loans").Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row).value & ")"
    OLAppointment.Start = Worksheets("Loans").Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).value & " " & 
    Format(Worksheets("Loans").Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row).value, "h:mm")
    OLAppointment.Body = Worksheets("Loans").Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).value & " County " & 
    vbNewLine & "HTH Income Limit " & formattedHTHLL & vbNewLine & _
        "FHA Bond 1-2 Household Income Limit " & formattedBond2LL & vbNewLine & "FHA Bond 3-4 
    Household Income Limit " & formattedBond3LL & vbNewLine & _
        "FHA Bond Sales Price limit " & formattedBondSP & vbNewLine & "Taxes " & 
    formattedTaxes & vbNewLine & "Seller Stamps " & formattedSellerStamps & _
        vbNewLine & "Builder Credit " & formattedCredit & vbNewLine & "Contract Date " & 
    Worksheets("Loans").Range("L" & ActiveCell.Row).value & vbNewLine & "Contract Commitment 
    Date: " & Worksheets("Loans").Range("G7").value & vbNewLine & "Estimated Down Payment: " & 
    _
    formattedDownPayment & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        
    OLAppointment.Location = "Borrower Cell"
    OLAppointment.Duration = 90
    OLAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 180
    OLAppointment.Display

    Set OLAppointment = Nothing
    Set OLNS = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Word object model for dealing with message bodies in Outlook. So, you may copy the content in Excel and just paste it in Outlook preserving all the markup. The [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene Astafiev but I am an amatuer coder, the coe you see there is me cobbling it together and modifying from what I find in google searched. I would not know how to do all that you suggested.